# How can I test the Deep MNIST for Experts code on a single image?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, mnist

I am just starting out with tensorflow and I want to test the trained model from tensorflow's [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros) on my own images. This is the code I used to test the Softmax Regression Model in the beginning of the tutorial on my own images:

```
with open("three.jpeg", "rb") as f:
    contents = f.read()

image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(contents, channels=1)
image_float = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, tf.float32)
resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(image_float, [28, 28])
resized_image = tf.reshape(resized_image, [784])

img = 1 - resized_image.eval() 

classification = sess.run(tf.argmax(y, 1), feed_dict={x: [img]})
plt.imshow(img.reshape(28, 28), cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
print ('NN predicted', classification[0])
```

Which worked fine for the softmax function but not for the Multilayer Convolutional Network. I tried changing  `y` in this line

```
classification = sess.run(tf.argmax(y, 1), feed_dict={x: [img]})
```

to `y_conv` but it gave me this error:

> InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor
>   'Placeholder_2' with dtype float   [[Node: Placeholder_2 =
>   Placeholderdtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

Comment: name your placeholders, then it will be easy to debug.

Answer (score 0):

There is a placeholder somewhere in your graph which you are not feeding. Odds are you need another `x` in your feed_dict, for the other network.